# How to create internal frames (child frames) in an applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jpanel, jinternalframe

I am trying to create a child frame to exist inside my applet and it should be bound to a JPanel.  I found this and that on the internet but nothing that worked.  I think something went wrong during the process and the darn thing is hidden or something.  Can someone please give me some help on this issue.

My source code follows...

```
public class EnableFrame {

  public void init() {

    EnableFrame theframe = new EnableFrame();
    theframe.setSize(550, 300);
    theframe.setVisible(true);
  }

  public EnableFrame()  {

    JPanel containall = new JPanel();

    JInternalFrame iframe = new JInternalFrame("New Frame",true,true);
    iframe.setBounds(10,10,150,150);
    iframe.getContentPane().add(containall);
    iframe.show(true);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

-Roland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JInternal` is normally associated with a `JDesktopPane`.

I order for the internal frame to appear on the screen, you must have added the frame to an appropriate container, such as a `JDesktopPane`

You may find [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) of some use.

Comment: Can I have a JDesktopPane even though I am using an applet?

Comment: Yep, so long as you're using a JApplet, otherwise you might have some problems

Comment: Ok sorry for the stupid question but the difference between a JApplet and an Applet is what the applet'c class is extended from like public class classthis extends JApplet{}

Comment: From the docs *An extended version of java.applet.Applet that adds support for the JFC/Swing component architecture. You can find task-oriented documentation about using JApplet in The Java Tutorial, in the section [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html)*

Comment: Another thing, can I have the JDesktop be constrained to the dimensions of my applet?

Comment: Sure, when you create the applet's UI, set it's layout manager to `BorderLayout` and then add the `JDesktopPane` to it

Comment: I know how to apply layouts to panels and such but, how would you apply it to an applet?  this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); ?

Comment: I dropped the command in my public EnableFrame() function and I'm getting error: non-static method setLayout(LayoutManager) cannot be referenced from a static context.  When I use this.setLayout... it works but when I use JApplet.setLayout... I get an error

Comment: Sorry, don't reference JApplet directly, you need to reference the instance (or if you're in the extended applet, simply use the method directly)

Answer (score 2):

my view only the comment

- even is possible there could be caused with some side_effect for `mouse` and `focus` event betweens heavyweight `(J)Applet` and lightweight `JInternalFrames` that complicated this idea, and heavyweight `(J)Applet` can jumping `toFront()`
- you'd don't do that and to use `JDesktopPane` from `JFrame` rather than for `(J)Applet`

Comment: Is there a way I could possibly have child frames within an applet?  This seems somewhat doomed...

Comment: `This seems somewhat doomed`, not I think `JDeskTop` and `JInternalFrames` are designated for descktop aplications, `(J)Applet` for embeded window in internet explorers